# How do docker linux container on windows get their ip address?

Tags: windows, networking, docker, docker-for-windows

Does docker (Windows) assign the IP address of a (Linux) container when it starts it, or is that static information pre-defined in /etc/hosts?

In my case I'm starting two simple containers that end up with a 172.17.0.[2|3] address which is not in my Windows routing table (`get-netroute|sls 172.17` returns nothing).  The yml only defines a forwarding port by no IP address info)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE       STATUS              PORTS                  
9f22bd3f770b        test-web    Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:8089->8080/tcp
388dcd1e5dd3        test-db     Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp
```

test-web has IP address 172.17.0.3

```
> docker inspect 9f22|sls IPA

            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
```

The Windows docker resources networking panel shows the "Docker subnet" to be 192.168.65.0/28 which is also not routed in Windows.

The documentation (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/) is pretty explicit that docker0 isn't/doesn't run under Windows and that per-container IP addressing is not possible.  It instructs to use port forwarding

ip address on the container returns:

```
> docker exec 9f22 ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
16: eth0@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.3/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Do these containers have any sort of external IP address?

Answer (score 0):

do you need to access your container application from external host?

if you need to access the container from external, you can expose the container port and map it to a port which is available in host. you can then access the container from external using your host IP:exposed port

sudo docker run -p 8000:80 image:v1

additional link which might help you understand further.
[https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-59-difference-between-exposing-and-publishing-ports#:~:text=You%20can%20expose%20a%20port,%2Dp%2080%3A80%20flag](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-59-difference-between-exposing-and-publishing-ports#:%7E:text=You%20can%20expose%20a%20port,%2Dp%2080%3A80%20flag).

Comment: That wasn't the question.  Docker on Windows works a bit differently and these are images from an external source.  I'm pretty sure the images are coming with their IP address set which seems undocker like, but I don't see any other way they could get the IP addrs they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Docker IP's are automatically assigned by docker (unless specified), they can be accessed by other docker containers or processes running on the same host. The default IP's are usually 172.17.x.x. And if you set `networks` in yml, the IP's become 192.168.x.x

In your case, 172.17.x.x are default ones, I don't think they're pre-set.

Comment: Thank you for confirming the 172.17... default.  That is what I would have expected, but I can't get to the containers (via an IP address) and the Windows host has no route to 172.17...  I also wonder what the "Docker subnet" of 192.168.65.0/28 is for in the Window's docker control panel.  My best guess at this point is that Windows is bring up Linux as a VM (HyperV), which is hosting the containers, but either not configuring the routing on the Win host side or expect manual configuration of routing.